# Selenium Robot Framework Pop Up Access

Tags: selenium, robotframework

I am not able to access a pop up window using `selenium` webdriver robot framework.

Steps:

1. site "http://carlightking.com/"
2. click on "Search By Vehicle" Tab.\
3. pop up window opens

I tried to access the pop up using "select window" keyword with some locators like `id` and `name` but was unsuccessful. It shows

```
ValueError: Window locator with prefix 'id' is not supported.
```

How can I select this pop up window and access elements over it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Problem is that the popup is inside a iFrame.

```
<iframe id="popup_selector" src="//carlightking.com/selector/selector-home-popup.php" width="100%"></iframe>
```

hence you have to explicitly select the iframe first

```
*** Test Case ***
CarLightKing
        Open Browser    http://carlightking.com/
        Wait Until Page contains Element            link=Search by Vehicle        5s
        Click Element           link=Search by Vehicle 
        Select Frame            id=popup_selector
```

Comment: Vivi, I tried selecting the elements inside the frame using locator like id = "drop_1" and xpath =  //*[@id="drop_1"]. But i was unable to. Can you please suggest how should i select elements inside an ifrmae. Also where should i read more about it as i have just started to learn it.